# difference in days, between two recordings

Tags: sql, self-join

I have this table

```
User | days
A    | 1
A    | 1   
A    | 2
B    | 2
B    | 5
```

and I'd like to have

```
User | difference_in_day
A    | 0
A    | 1   
B    | 3
```

I think I have to do a self-join, but i don't know how to compare a row to the next one only.

Do we need to add a row position in the first table with this condition ? :

```
WHERE  a.row_position+1=b.row_position
```

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: I'm working on Microsoft Sql Server

Comment: If you're comparing one row with the next row, you're relying on the data coming through in a specific order. Is there an ID field or a SortBy field in your table which you can use? If not, then you can't assume that the order will be the same when you rerun your query.

Comment: The data are already order by id, day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
;with T as(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by User, Days) Rnum from YourTable
)
select 
    distinct a.User, 
    b.Days-a.Days difference_in_day 
from T a left join T b on a.Rnum=b.Rnum-1 
where b.User is not null
```

Sample

```
declare @tbl as table(xUser nvarchar(1), xDays int)
insert into @tbl values 
('A', 1),
('A', 1),
('A', 2),
('B', 2),
('B', 5)

select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by xUser, xDays) Rnum from @tbl

;with T as(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by xUser, xDays) Rnum from @tbl
)
select 
    distinct a.xUser, 
    b.xDays-a.xDays difference_in_day 
from T a left join T b on a.Rnum=b.Rnum-1 
where b.xUser is not null
```